# How to know if the object is formed by deserialization in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

Is there any way to know whether the object was deserialized from an XML file in C#?
What I want to do is to do a post-processing to my object if it was deserialized.
Is there any function or property provides that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "by `XmlSerializer`", then : no, not usually.

The concept of "serialization callbacks" exists (pre-serialize, post-serialize, pre-deserialize, post-deserialize) and is well understood and supported by most every serializer I can think of... ***except*** `XmlSerializer`, which doesn't support it *at all*. The main interception point you get in `XmlSerializer` is if the type implements `IXmlSerializable`, but if you do that you need to do *all* the work yourself, which is : hard (plus you lose schema support).

Your best bet would be to run a method explicitly after your call to `Deserialize`. If you need to make this generic, then perhaps put the method on an interface, so that your deserialize code *basically* does:

```
var newObj = serializer.Deserialize(source);
var forCallback = newObj as ISerializationCallbacks; // <== you define this
if(forCallback != null) forCallback.AfterDeserialize();
return newObj;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about the internal objects?

Comment: @user2302005 unless it has changed, you can't; unless I'm entirely wrong, of course. Well, you can manually explore the tree, of course.